# Accuracy vs AUROC in balanced data sets

Tags: prediction, model-evaluation

Im doing an analysis on tennis match prediction. Data is completely balanced and false positives are as important as false negatives. AUROC evaluates FPR and TPR at different thresholds, which doesn't seem to make sense to me because why would you want any other thresholds than 0.5? Is there any reason to use AUROC instead of accuracy in this case?